# RMS calculation result always zero

Tags: c#

I'd like to calculate RMS value from a bunch of decimal numbers in list. But the result always zero. Any suggestion?

```
list0.Add(0.5);
list0.Add(0.5);
list0.Add(0.5);
list0.Add(0.6);
            
//RMS
double square = 0;
double mean = 0, root = 0;
int n = list0.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    square += (int)Math.Pow(list0[i], 2);                
}
mean = (square / (int)(n));
root = (double)Math.Sqrt(mean);

Console.WriteLine(root);
```

Comment: remove the casts to (int)

Comment: @MitchWheat the division is not the problem, though - it is the cast `(int)Math.Pow` which has to be removed.

Comment: correct.........I did also mention removing the (int) casts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your code: I removed the unnecessary int casts from the program.

Please try it:

```
var list0 = new List<double>();

list0.Add(0.5);
list0.Add(0.5);
list0.Add(0.5);
list0.Add(0.6);

//RMS
double square = 0;
double mean = 0;
double root = 0;
int n = list0.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    square += Math.Pow(list0[i], 2);
}

mean = square / n;
root = Math.Sqrt(mean);

Console.WriteLine(root);
```

Comment: While this might answer the question it would be a lot better as an answer if you described what you changed and why it fixed the problem.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I have modified the answer.